# .NET JSON.decode() fails for large arrays

Tags: javascript, .net, arrays, json, serialization

MVC 4 ASP.NET Web API application :

I have a JSON array of form :

```
var json = "{
    'mapset':
    [
        {
            'id': '1',
            'key': 'key1',
            'value': 'value1',
            'timestamp': '2014-02-12T08:50:54.594Z'
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'key': 'key2',
            'value': 'value2',
            'timestamp': '2014-02-12T08:50:54.594Z'
        },
    ]
}";

dynamic data = System.Web.Helpers.JSON.decode(json);
```

For array with 10K elements of ~1K bytes each, `JSON.Decode()` works like a charm.

For 100K elements fails with error :

> System.ArgumentException: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.Parameter name: input   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)   at System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(String value)

How can I set the limit higher ?

I am aware of the other post regarding this topic :

[Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config)

However the answers provided there do not solve my specific problem.

I am directly using `JSON.Decode()` within an MVC4 app and so modification of `web.config` settings will not apply.  And `JSON.Decode()` performs deserialization of a JSON string to a .NET JSON object ( not serialization of a .NET JSON object to a JSON string ).

Comment: Did you not search the clues in the error message?

Comment: Yes I know this is a config issue but the other post does not provide a solution. Please see my edits in original question. Please reopen.

Comment: Help if you put that info in to start.

Answer (score 2):

[This blog article](https://www.abstractmethod.co.uk/blog/2018/9/maxjsonlength-error-when-using-jsondecode/) by Michael Witty shows how to solve the problem.  Basically, while it is not possible to directly override the `MaxJsonLength` of the underlying `JavaScriptSerializer` used by `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode`, one can very easily replicate `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode` with a few lines and there-by control the max length.

The following is a tested and working DynamicJsonObjectFormatter.  It has a static method `dynamic DynamicJsonObjectFormatter.Decode(string json)` that duplicates `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode`, but gives you control of the max length:

```
public class DynamicJsonObjectFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public static dynamic Decode(string json, int maxLength=0)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                return null;
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            if( maxLength>0) {
                serializer.MaxJsonLength = maxLength;
            }
            var deserialized = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);
            if (deserialized != null)
            {
                var dictValues = deserialized as IDictionary<string, object>;
                if (dictValues != null)
                    return new DynamicJsonObject(dictValues);
                var arrayValues = deserialized as object[];
                if (arrayValues != null)
                {
                    return new DynamicJsonArray(arrayValues);
                }
            }
            log.Error("Internal: Attempt to deserialize unrecognized JSON string as DynamicJsonObject");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Internal: exception deserializing JSON", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
    override public object ReadFromStream(Type type, System.IO.Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader strdr = null;
        try
        {
            strdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(readStream);
            string json = strdr.ReadToEnd();
            int maxLength = 33554432; //Int32.MaxValue;
            return Decode(json, maxLength);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Internal: exception deserializing JSON", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (strdr != null)
            {
                strdr.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public DynamicJsonObjectFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"));
        //SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(false, true));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return (type == typeof(DynamicJsonObject)) || (type == typeof(DynamicJsonArray));
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

(Note: the `strdr.ReadToEnd()` may also give you an issue with large files.  It's size limit can be controlled with

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxRequestLength="200000" />
    <!-- maxRequestLength is in KB, not B -->
</system.web>
```

in your Web.config file.  See [this article](https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1544/how-to-resolve-maximum-request-length-exceeded.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` does the trick for me.

It is ugly I think, but with the JavaScriptSerializer, I'm able to set the maxJsonLength to a big value:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ser.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // <-- should probably not use that huge value
var jsonArtikel = ser.Serialize(Model);
```